# Gerrit Code Reivew not accepting ssh credentials from Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, gerrit

I have been trying to get a Jenkins build to pull from my Gerrit repo using SSH. I created a user named jenkinsbuild in Gerrit, and entered the public key for the user.

I am using the Git SCM option and using the Credentials plugin. For my Credentials, I set the user name the jenkinsbuild and enter the private key directly (rather than pointing to the key file).

My SCM configuration looks like this

**Repository URL:** ssh://jenkinsbuild@domain.com:29418/test/testgit

**Credentials** jenkinsbuild (Jenkins Credentials)

When I run the build, it gets hung up on trying to fetch from the GIT repo. It polls for 10 minutes, then the process times out. I have looked at /var/log/secure on the Gerrit server and seen errors like:

```
Jun  8 11:06:25 xxxxx sshd[9887]: Invalid user jenkinsbuild from xx.xx.xxx.xxx
Jun  8 11:06:25 xxxxx sshd[9887]: debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 0
Jun  8 11:06:25 xxxxx sshd[9887]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 8
Jun  8 11:06:25 xxxxx sshd[9888]: input_userauth_request: invalid user jenkinsbuild
```

In order to debug that issue, I logged on to the Jenkins server as jenkinsbuild and tried to do a git clone of the repository. It worked (after some tinkering). I am not sure why I can clone directly from the server but not from Jenkins.

Does anyone have any advice on how I can further debug this issue?

Comment: Have you looked at the gerrit/log/error_log and gerrit/log/sshd_log files on the Gerrit server? Any clues?

Comment: The sshd_log file only seems to be logging the successful logins. When I attempt to do it from my build (where it fails), I don't see any new entries. There are plenty of errors logged in the error_log, but the only one that corresponds to the timing of my requests is "[2016-06-08 15:14:02,673] ERROR com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.ReplicationQueue : Cannot replicate to xxxxx:/opt/git/ttadd/qcegpos.git
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: xxxxx:/opt/git/ttadd/qcegpos.git: Missing unknown bc751a060521b1b4e23795464a3fd398fbd09996
"

Comment: Uhm... maybe Jenkins is waiting for a user response like: The authenticity of host <server>:<port> can't be established. RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:<key>. Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

Comment: That is possible. It doesnt show up in the Console log for the build, though. Is there a switch or something that can be provided to auto-respond to it? Also, is there a way to increase the verbosity of logging? I tried adding a -v to the Git URL because it was the only thing I could edit, but it didnt work.

Comment: Ok I regenerated the rsa keys without a passphrase and now it works, so im guessing it was the prompt. I had provided the passphrase as part of the credentials, but I guess I that is not working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the GIT plugin for Jenkins (at least the version I am on) doesnt support ssh keys with passphrases. Seems kind of odd since it uses the Credentials plugin, which allows you to provide a passphrase.

There are plenty of bugs open for it, including [JENKINS-20879](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20879)

The solution was to regenerate the ssh keys without a passphrase.